# Rails how to group by date and count records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my model I have:

```
start = 3.weeks.ago

kliks = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
kliks = kliks.group("date(created_at)")
```

How do I count all the records for each day as total?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that this should work:

```
kliks = count(
  :group => 'date(created_at)',
  :conditions => { :created_at => start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now }
)
```

This will return you a hash mapping dates to their count.